# Table rows not working as siblings for jquery requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, siblings

What makes something a sibling for jquery requests?

I want the content within all cells of my table to act as siblings for my jquery requests. Currently only the td values in the same row act as siblings of each other. The next row of td's act as a different "family" if you will.

```
i.e <table> 
      <tr>
        <td> content here </td>
        <td> more content </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> content here </td>
        <td> more content </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

     $("td").click(function () { 
        $(this).siblings().addClass('fadeClick');
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('noFade');
       }
```

See jfiddle for full code: https://jsfiddle.net/nsn3bpep/7/

(I want all boxes, in both rows, aside from the one hovered/clicked on to be half opaque out)

Comment: your fiddle seems to work! what's the problem?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nsn3bpep/7/ When I split up the images on different rows, the images no longer act as siblings to all other images, only the ones in the same row.

Comment: so, it works as designed as you have one sibling each per td!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select all `td` elements and use this collection instead of siblings. Something like this:

```
var $td = $("td");
$td.click(function () {
    $("#content").html($(this).find(".hover-content").html());
    $('img[class*="wp-image-"]').removeClass('myClickState');
    $(this).find('img[class*="wp-image-"]').addClass('myClickState');
    divContent = $("#content").html();
    $td.not(this).addClass('fadeClick').removeClass('noFade');
    $(this).removeClass('fadeClick');
});
$td.hover(function () {
    $("#content").html($(this).find(".hover-content").html());
    $(this).addClass('noFade');
    $td.not(this).removeClass('noFade').addClass('fade');
}, function () {
    $("#content").html(divContent);
    $td.not(this).removeClass('fade');
    $(this).removeClass('noFade');
});
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/nsn3bpep/8/

Comment: Thank you! I've never used a collection before, but this seems very useful when sibling doesn't make sense as in my case above.